# Megger manual warning clarification

Tags: current, current-limiting, tools, manual

[image]

[image]

When a manual of a Megger warns:

> The measurement time must not
> exceed 10 seconds if the measured resistance is less than 1.5 MΩ at 500 VDC position or less than 5 MΩ at 1000 VDC position"

The manual doesn't give more details beyond that.

Does it mean that the measurement time can be 10 seconds at any resistance value below the mentioned ones, even at 10 Ω or even at short (0 Ω resistance)?

I assume that the 10 seconds limit is related to the internal heating in the current limiting circuit inside the Megger (which, btw, limits the current to 2.5 mA), but does this 10 seconds
warning refer to the worst case of a short circuit (2.5 mA × 500 V = 1.25 W)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: Yes.

You can short it for up to 10 seconds at a time, followed by a cooldown period.

As you can see on the pretty pictures you provided (thank you!), there's a TO-220 transistor in the device. This transistor provides the output current and gets hot at higher currents. Since it doesn't have a heatsink, you'll have to make sure to not measure for so long that it overheats.

Comment: Is 5 minutes considered enough cooldown period time for the transistor to cool?I guess that it depends on how much the transistor was heated,but for the worst case,what is the recommended cooldown period?

Comment: 5 minutes should be more than enough.

Comment: As i would like to make my measurements faster and as you said that 5 minutes is more than enough,may you specify the optimal cooldown period?

Comment: You'd have to figure that out by taking a measurement and measuring the transistor's temperature at regular intervals afterwards to find out how long it takes for it to cool down again. There are too many unknowns for me to give you any better estimate than "5 minutes should be okay".